# Speech to text RecognitionAudio fromBytes always returns blank result

Tags: c#, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use google speech to text in my code. I have live streaming with video and audio of m3U8 format. 
I am using FFMPEG to extract audio from live url.
Trying to send this extracted audio to google api (without saving on disk) to get back transcription. Streaming is done with chunks.
API never returns any result and also never throws any error. Can someone tell me why the results are always blank?
Note: Using byte[] to send extracted audio to google api.                 Result: API returns blank result without any error message. using below code to call RecognitionAudio FromBytes.

```
            outputStream = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
            int read;
            while ((read = outputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "Demo.json");
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
            var longOperation = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
            Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
            EnableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel = true,
            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
            LanguageCode = "en",
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromBytes(ms.ToArray()));
            //    longOperation = longOperation.PollUntilCompleted();
            //  var response = longOperation.Results;
            foreach (var result in longOperation.Results)
            {
            foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
            }
            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve] of the issue as described?  Especially one that incorporates this live URL that doesn't give you any expected results.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with code. outputStream is Stream output from ffmpeg. Here I am extracting audio data from url which has Video and Audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank response can indicate incorrect audio encoding. Troubleshooting is found [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/troubleshooting#returns_an_empty_response).

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply. How to find that encoding is not correct? as I am extracting audio from live url using ffmpeg without saving it on disk. It is not an audio file. To extract this audio data I am using below command -i {m3u8Url} -vn -acodec copy -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f s16le pipe:1  Do you think this problem is because of s16le format?